# check checkbox on populated dropdown value selection via javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, checkbox, drop-down-menu

i got for the 6 Scenario what i want to do 6 checkboxes:

```
    <tr style="height: 21px;">
<td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;">COB</td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"><input name="COB" type="checkbox" id="COB" value="1" <?php if($_GET['COB'] == '1'){  echo 'checked="checked"';}?>/>           </td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;">SMT</td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;">  <input name="SMT" id="SMT" type="checkbox" value="1" <?php if($_GET['SMT'] == '1'){  echo 'checked="checked"';}?>/> </td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 21px;">
<td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"></td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"></td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;">BGA</td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;">  <input name="BGA" id="BGA" type="checkbox" value="1" <?php if($_GET['BGA'] == '1'){  echo 'checked="checked"';}?>/> </td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 21px;">
<td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"></td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"></td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;">  TSOP Typ 1 </td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"><input name="TSOP" id="TSOP" type="checkbox" value="1"<?php if($_GET['TSOP'] == '1'){  echo 'checked="checked"';}?> /></td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 21px;">
<td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"></td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"></td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"> TSOP Typ 2</td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"><input name="TSOP2" id="TSOP2" type="checkbox" value="2"<?php if($_GET['TSOP'] == '2'){  echo 'checked="checked"';}?> />   </td>

</tr>
<tr style="height: 21px;">
<td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"></td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"></td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"> LGA</td>
<td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"><input name="LGA" id="LGA" type="checkbox" value="1"<?php if($_GET['LGA'] == '1'){  echo 'checked="checked"';}?> />    </td>
</tr>
```

And here the PHP Part how i populate the Dropdown.

```
<td style="width: 14.2857%; height: 21px;">  <select id="FlashID" name="FlashID" onchange="FlashFunction()" size="1" >

                    <option disabled selected value> </option>;                             
            <?php
            foreach($connection->query($flash) as $m)
            {
                        if($m['FlashID'] == $_GET['FlashID']){
                $isSelected = 'selected="selected"';
            }else{
                $isSelected = '';
            }
            echo "<option data-COB='".$m['COB']."' data-SMT='".$m['SMT']."' data-BGA='".$m['BGA']."' data-TSOP='".$m['TSOP']."' data-LGA='".$m['LGA']."' value='" . $m['FlashID'] . "'".$isSelected."  >" .$m['SAP'] ."</option>";

            }
            ?> 
            </td>
```

Here is the SQL Table for the poplated Dropdown

```
FlashID   SAP   COB   SMT   BGA   TSOP    LGA
1        102292  0     1     0     2       0
3        102293  0     1     0     2       0
4        102294  0     1     0     2       0
5        102296  0     1     0     0       1
6        102412  0     1     0     1       0
7        102413  0     1     0     1       0
8        102414  0     1     0     1       0
9        102651  0     1     0     2       0
10       102652  0     1     0     2       0
11       102664  0     1     0     2       0
```

This is my not working Javascript Part:

```
<script>
function FlashFunction(){
var index = document.getElementById("FlashID").selectedIndex;
var COB = document.getElementById("FlashID").options[index].getAttribute("data-COB");
var SMT = document.getElementById("FlashID").options[index].getAttribute("data-SMT");
var BGA = document.getElementById("FlashID").options[index].getAttribute("data-BGA");
var TSOP = document.getElementById("FlashID").options[index].getAttribute("data-TSOP");
var LGA = document.getElementById("FlashID").options[index].getAttribute("data-LGA");
document.getElementsByName("COB")[0].value = COB;
document.getElementsByName("SMT")[0].value = SMT;
document.getElementsByName("BGA")[0].value = BGA;
document.getElementsByName("TSOP")[0].value = TSOP;
document.getElementsByName("TSOP2")[0].value = TSOP;
document.getElementsByName("LGA")[0].value = LGA;
}
</script>
```

Notice the TSOP can be value 1 or 2.

**for ex.** You see already if I select FlashID 6. TSOP and SMT Checkbox should be checked.

But atm I have no idea, how I can handle this in why my Javascript is not working Can someone help?

Comment: if you select FlashID 6, what is happening here? What do you mean by `Javascript is not working` ?

Comment: TSOP and SMT Checkbox should be checked, but they arent

Comment: @Daniel is it possible to create workable example here https://codesandbox.io using static data

Answer (score 2):

I notice that in the last 3 checkboxes you do not have a space between the value and the php code.

This:

```
<td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"><input name="TSOP2" id="TSOP2" type="checkbox" value="2"<?php if($_GET['TSOP'] == '2'){  echo 'checked="checked"';}?> />   </td>
```

can go to this after php is executed:

```
<td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"><input name="TSOP2" id="TSOP2" type="checkbox" value="2"checked="checked" />   </td>
```

and should be like this:

```
td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"><input name="TSOP2" id="TSOP2" type="checkbox" value="2" checked="checked" />   </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [DOM Standard](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-nonelementparentnode-getelementbyid), elemnet IDs should be unique within the entire document. While in your code two `input` are having the same id `TSOP`.

I have created to codepen [sample](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oRVzxg) for you to show that JAVASCRIPT part is working, there may be some issue with your PHP code.

```js
function FlashFunction() {

  var index = document.getElementById("FlashID").selectedIndex;


  var SMT = document
    .getElementById("FlashID")
    .options[index].getAttribute("data-SMT");

  var BGA = document
    .getElementById("FlashID")
    .options[index].getAttribute("data-BGA");
  var TSOP = document
    .getElementById("FlashID")
    .options[index].getAttribute("data-TSOP");


  var LGA = document
    .getElementById("FlashID")
    .options[index].getAttribute("data-LGA");


  document.getElementsByName("COB")[0].value = COB;
  document.getElementsByName("SMT")[0].value = SMT;
  document.getElementsByName("BGA")[0].value = BGA;
  document.getElementsByName("TSOP")[0].value = TSOP;
  document.getElementsByName("TSOP2")[0].value = TSOP;
  document.getElementsByName("LGA")[0].value = LGA;
  
  if (TSOP == 1) {
    document.getElementsByName("TSOP")[0].checked = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<select id="FlashID" name="FlashID" onchange="FlashFunction()">
  <option data-SMT="1" value="volvo">102292</option>
  <option data-SMT="1" value="saab">102293</option>
  <option data-SMT="1" data-TSOP="1" value="mercedes">102412</option>
</select>
<table>
  <tr style="height: 21px;">
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;">COB</td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"><input name="COB" type="checkbox" id="COB" value="1" /> </td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;">SMT</td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"> <input name="SMT" id="SMT" type="checkbox" value="1" </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height: 21px;">
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"></td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"></td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;">BGA</td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"> <input name="BGA" id="BGA" type="checkbox" value="1" </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height: 21px;">
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"></td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"></td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"> TSOP Typ 1 </td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"><input name="TSOP" id="TSOP" type="checkbox" value="1" </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height: 21px;">
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"></td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"></td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"> TSOP Typ 2</td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"><input name="TSOP2" id="TSOP2" type="checkbox" value="2" </td>

  </tr>
  <tr style="height: 21px;">
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"></td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"></td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;"> LGA</td>
    <td style="width: 25%; height: 21px;">
      <input name="LGA" id="LGA" type="checkbox" value="1" </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Edit. I changed. Notice the TSOP can be value 1 or 2.

Comment: is it possible for you to create a demo with static data? or can you add the  HTML produces after PHP as it's interesting to look if  `data-TSOP='".$m['TSOP']."'` is an array or number

Answer (score 0):

you do not check the checkboxs like this

```
document.getElementsByName("COB")[0].value = COB;
document.getElementsByName("SMT")[0].value = SMT;
document.getElementsByName("BGA")[0].value = BGA;
document.getElementsByName("TSOP")[0].value = TSOP;
document.getElementsByName("TSOP2")[0].value = TSOP;
document.getElementsByName("LGA")[0].value = LGA;
```

the correct way is like this :

```
document.getElementById("ItemId").checked = true; 
// because there is one <input ...> i use getEmelentById instead of getElementsById
```

in your program i think this is the correct javascript you need to use is :

```
<script>
function FlashFunction(){
var index = document.getElementById("FlashID").selectedIndex;
var COB = document.getElementById("FlashID").options[index].getAttribute("data-COB");
var SMT = document.getElementById("FlashID").options[index].getAttribute("data-SMT");
var BGA = document.getElementById("FlashID").options[index].getAttribute("data-BGA");
var TSOP = document.getElementById("FlashID").options[index].getAttribute("data-TSOP");
var LGA = document.getElementById("FlashID").options[index].getAttribute("data-LGA");
if (COB == 1 ) {
    document.getElementById("COB").checked= true;
} else {
    document.getElementById("COB").checked= false;
}
if (SMT == 1 ) {
    document.getElementById("SMT").checked= true;
} else {
    document.getElementById("SMT").checked= false;
}
if (BGA == 1 ) {
    document.getElementById("BGA").checked= true;
} else {
    document.getElementById("BGA").checked= false;
}
if (TSOP == 1 ) {
    document.getElementById("TSOP").checked= true;
} else {
    document.getElementById("TSOP").checked= false;
}
if (TSOP == 2 ) {
    document.getElementById("TSOP2").checked= true;
} else {
    document.getElementById("TSOP2").checked= false;
}
if (LGA == 1 ) {
    document.getElementById("LGA").checked= true;
} else {
    document.getElementById("LGA").checked= false;
}

}
</script>
```